# CSS - Problems with getting 3 div's to be floated and centered, within the container div.. (contains code and crude diagram)

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float, centering

I am having problems centering 3 divs that are within a "container" so to say.

It should basically look something like this (forgive my crude example):

```
    ______________________
   |  ___    ___     ___  |
   | |___|  |___|   |___| |
   |______________________|
```

The problem that i am having though, is that i cant seem to figure out the css to get these 3 divs to be laid out as in my crude example.

Because the design is supposed to be elastic and expand or contract over different resolutions, thus presenting roughly the same appearance over varying resolutions.

At the moment the div's are floated left and there is a larger gap between the last div and the container, compared to the first div. I am trying to get them all to fit snugly in the middle...

Here is the code relating to this:

```
.searchResult {
    padding: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
    margin: 2% 2.5%;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 2px outset #003399;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
}

.bizDesc {
    margin-right: 2%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 35.5%;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 2px outset #003399;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
}

.bizAddr {
    margin-right: 2%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 2px outset #003399;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
}

.bizCont {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    height: 140px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px / 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 2px outset #003399;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -ms-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666666;
}
```

The first bit of css relates to the container, the next 3, relate to the 3 divs in order from left to right. So that my example comes out something like this:

```
    ______________________
   | ___    ___     ___   |
   ||___|  |___|   |___|  |
   |______________________|
```

If anyone would spare some wisdom and provide me with some input into this, as i am sure that the answer is quite simple, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

HTML

```
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box{
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
```

Whatever you do with the inner boxes is irrelevant, as long as the container has margin auto

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this is not working out for me.

Comment: It should. Can you make a jsdiffle? To be clear, #container is not the same as the dialog box. Is an extra block to center the blocks in the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'd be easiest to add one more div in there... That way, the outer div in your diagram would control how the div acts in the container/tag that contains it. The div you would add would surround the 3 boxes and would then have flexibility to the margins/float/etc to the outer div.

Assuming that "searchResult" is the outer div, a structure like so:

```
<div class="searchResult">
    <div class="divClassToAdd">
        <div class="bizDesc">...</div>
        <div class="bizAddr">...</div>
        <div class="bizCont">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. As @Dbugger has mentioned in his edit too, having that margin set to auto for "divClassToAdd" will give you what you're looking for. Play around with the style, see what fits best. :)